# How can I get the key name and its value from an array within a JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

**My Problem**

In my JSON file I have an object within an object with a value which is an array of key/value pairs. I am having trouble outputting each key name and its value.

**My Code**

*menu.json*

```
{"themenu":[
    {
        "stuff": "stuffs",
        "pages": [
            {"name1": "page111"},
            {"name2": "page222"},
            {"name3": "page333"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

*menu.js*

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('menu.json', function(data) {
        $(data.themenu).each(function() {
            var stuff = this.stuff;
            alert(stuff); // alerts 'stuffs'
            $(this.pages).each(function(key, value) { 
                var pageName = this.key;
                var pageUrl = this.value;
                alert(pageName + ' ' + pageUrl);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

**What I Require**

I want to output the name of the key and its corresponding value so it would be the same as this...

```
alert('name1 page111');
alert('name2 page222');
alert('name3 page333');
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried a few things including...

```
$(data.pages).each(function(key, value) { 
    var pageName = this.key;
    var pageUrl = this.value;
})
```

...and a bunch more voodoo that I'm too embarrassed to post.

Comment: Try `var pageName = Object.keys(this)[0], pageUrl = this[pageName]; })`

Comment: @haim770 ! I love how you used the variable to get the value! Please post as answer so I can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code, it will work. I just changed some content of your code, try this::

```
var json_data = {"themenu":[
    {
        "stuff": "stuffs",
        "pages": [
            {"name1": "page111"},
            {"name2": "page222"},
            {"name3": "page333"}
        ]
    }
]};
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $.getJSON(json_data, function(data) {
        $(json_data.themenu).each(function() {
            var stuff = this.stuff;
            alert(stuff); // alerts 'stuffs'
            $(this.pages).each(function(key, value) { 
                $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                    var pageName = key;
                    var pageUrl = value;
                    alert(pageName + ' ' + pageUrl);
                });
            });
        });
//    })
});
```

Assuming `var json_data` having your data, Replace it as you need.

Comment: Hi Rana, thankyou, this works great! I think though I will have to accept haim's comment as the answer (if he posts it)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over an array with vanilla JavaScript with the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, and then retrieve the keys for an object with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
var json_data = {
  "themenu": [{
    "stuff": "stuffs",
    "pages": [{
      "name1": "page111"
    }, {
      "name2": "page222"
    }, {
      "name3": "page333"
    }]
  }]
}


json_data['themenu'].forEach(function(menu) {
  menu.pages.forEach(function(page) {
    alert(Object.keys(page)[0] + ' ' + page[Object.keys(page)[0]]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works fine for me! However, I will probably accept haim's answer (first comment) because it makes the least changes to the original code (jquery) and is quite concise.

Answer (score 2):

When looping your JSON and using `this.key`/`this.value` you literally search for key `key`/`value` (if it would be `{'key': ..., 'value': ...}`.

Your `$.each(this.pages, function (key, value)` gives you array of your desired value. You can loop once more to get key/value as text:

```js
var json = {
  "pages": [{
    "name1": "page111"
  }, {
    "name2": "page222"
  }, {
    "name3": "page333"
  }]
};

$.each(json.pages, function(k, v) {
  console.log(k, v);
  $.each(this, function(key, value) {
    console.log('->', key, value);
    //alert(keyName + ' ' + value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```